# Hide 2 DIV's when one has no content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a slideshow with thumbnails associated with each slide. So I have 10 DIV's that represent slides like this...

```
<div class="SSSlide clip_frame grpelem slide" id="u751"><!-- image -->

        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<img class='img' src={$row['img']} width='350px' height='225px'>";
        }
        ?>              

 </div>
```

> And 10 other DIV's that represent the thumbnails

```
    <div class="SSSlide thumbnail" id="u780"><!-- associated div -->
I am a thumbnail linked to a slide
</div>
```

When the query within each slide DIV has no results returned (no contents within), I would like to remove that DIV and it's associated thumbnail DIV. I'd like this to happen when page opens so whatever slides are emtpy, the slide itself and it's thumb DIV will be removed completely (not just hidden)

I've looked around google and such, but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: hide the whole `div` when `$row['img']` is empty?

Comment: why are you outputting them in php if they are empty? Wouldn't it just be simpler to catch it on server?

Comment: not very understand about the thumbnail, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the thumbnail content into database as well.

> First method - Select Query

You can directly deselect the empty content rows. For example:

```
$sql = "select * from image_tbl" where (your condition) and img != ''";
```

> Second method - If Clause

```
<div class="SSSlide clip_frame grpelem slide" id="u751"><!-- image -->
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         if($row['img'] != ""){
            echo "<img class='img' src={$row['img']} width='350px' height='225px'>";
        }
    }
    ?>   
</div>
```

---

Here I'm assuming you storing img and thumbnail in database:

```
<div class="SSSlide clip_frame grpelem slide" id="u751"><!-- image -->

    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<img class='img' src={$row['img']} width='350px' height='225px'>";
        $thumbnail_str .= "
            <div class='SSSlide thumbnail' id='u780'><!-- associated div -->
                $row[thumbnail]
            </div>
        ";
    }
    ?>              

</div>
echo $thumbnail_str;
```

Hope these helps! :)